# Why can't I add to my array in this particular function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function in which I loop through and perform a small set of queries that return chunks of data using Breeze.js. Every section of the code works but one single line (where I try to add the results of the query to the array). I have tried all kinds of things and just can't seem to figure out WHY it doesn't work.

```
function doStuff(sourceArray, outputObservable, errorObservable) {
    var arr = [];

    _.each(sourceArray, function (sourceItem) {
        return breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("SomeTable")
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(getSucceeded)
            .fail(getFailed);

        function getSucceeded(data) {
            _.each(data.results, function (item) {
                console.log(item); //This works
                arr.push(item);  //This doesn't work
            });
        }

        function getFailed(error) {
            errorObservable("Error retrieving data: " + error.message);
        }
    });

    outputObservable(arr);
}
```

This will output all of the results of each query to the console but it will not at the results to the array. However, if I change the second line to `var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];` then those values will reflect in outputObservable.

**EDIT:** Full solution is below.

```
function doStuff(sourceArray, outputObservable, errorObservable) {
    var promises = [];
    var arr = [];

    //Create an array of promises
    _.forEach(sourceArray, function (item) {
        promises.push(getDataFromServer(item.val1, item.val2));
    });

    //Wait for all promises to resolve, then set output
    Q.all(promises).then(function () {
        outputObservable(arr);
    });

    function getDataFromServer(filter1, filter2) {
        var p1 = breeze.Predicate.create("field1", "==", filter1);
        var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create("field2", "==", filter2);

        return breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("SomeTable")
            .where(p1.and(p2))
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(getSucceeded)
            .fail(getFailed);

        function getSucceeded(data) {
            _.each(data.results, function (item) {
                arr.push(item);
            });
        }

        function getFailed(error) {
            errorObservable("Error retrieving processes: " + error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? There is no indication of *if/when that line runs*, it wouldn't put *something* in the result. (So then a valid hypothesis is that it never runs; or doesn't run soon enough.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Breeze, but I suspect `EntityQuery` is asynchronous? If so `outputObservable` will be called before your callback (`getSucceeded`) gets fired.... but you should be able to see that from your `console.log`.

Comment: Doh, it is because the outputObservable(arr) gets called first =/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the classic pitfall with asynchronism. `getSucceeded` is called *asynchronously*, meaning that you pass it as a callback to `EntityQuery` which in turn will call it *at a later time*.

By the time your `_.each(sourceArray, ...)` returns, all queries will have started *but are still running*. None of those will have completed yet, and none of your callbacks will have been called yet. Thus, `arr` is still unchanged by the time you pass it to `outputObservable`. You should be able to notice this in your debugger: add a `console.log` before `outputObservable` and you'll see that it will be called *before* any of the `console.log(item)` calls.

You only want to call `outputObservable` when *all* asynchronous queries have completed. I'm not too familiar with Breeze or underscore.js, but you need to combine the promises returned by `execute()` into a new promise. This new promise gets resolved when *all* promises become resolved, so you should attach a `then` callback to it and call `outputObservable`.

Comment: Breeze uses Q under the hood for it's promises. How would I got about combining the promises in this forEach loop?

Comment: Never mind, I played around for a bit and found out a solution. Edited answer to show.